# I cant import React BridgeModule on header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native

I am working on a node module that integrates with a native react app. I need to implement in the iOS project the functionalities of the node module written in "swift" and make it available in react. It turns out that when I try to import "RCTBridgeModule", it doesn't exist. I tried various "solutions" with no results.

I clarify that I have changed the name of the xcodeproj (the node module's iOS project) since it collides with the name of a framework that I plan to add.

Honestly, this problem gives me a headache and I don't have much experience with iOS development environments.

Xcode: Version 12.0.1 (12A7300).

Attached screenshots of some files and settings:

[image]

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You should put stuff in between the guard ```#ifndef ...``` and ```#endif``` for starters. Then you won't need to test if you already included the header or not. I see you have two y's (```yy```) in your interface name. Not that you should define interfaces in your bridging header anyway ... And why do you include ```RCTBridgeModule``` in two different ways, one with quotes and one with angle brackets. I think this is concocted from two different and incompatible samples. Maybe pick just one of the samples you've used and run with that?

Comment: thanks for your reply! 

Even with the recommended changes I can't access the file I try to import. It should be clarified that this header file is a bridge between swift and objetive-C